# Why default java max heap is 1/4th of Physical memory?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have read couples of articles on java heap space and found out that the default max heap for JVM is 1/4th of the actual physical space. But none of the article had reason for this ?
Whats the reason of having it as 1/4th of actual memory?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Comment: The docs you link to state that the default max heap size is *smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB*

Comment: That is some heuristic. There is no strict formula. They collected some statistics and found that it is good for average case.

Comment: @talex Are you sure on that ?

Comment: @ernest_k I even saw the maxramfraction for my jvm, its 4 . that means to sue 1/4th of the available physical memory.

Comment: @RajThakur I don't have source for it, but I hear that many time, so not 100% sure.

Comment: @talex sure even i wasnt able to find any promising info on this.

Comment: They had to provide _some_ default, so they said `1/4` and documented it. Why is the default number of buckets in `HasMap` 16 or `ArrayList` 10? Same reason.

Comment: I remember the times when the default heap size was 64MB, which was still there when we already had multiple GB of RAM. The details of the new defaults didn’t really matter, anything was better than that…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dates back to JDK 5, which introduced JVM ergonomics.  Prior to this, the JVM would set very small defaults for the heap space.  JDK 1.1 had a default of 16Mb for both Xms and Xmx, JDK 1.2 changed this to Xms of 1Mb and Xmx of 64Mb by default. In JDK 1.3, Xms default increased to 2Mb.

Since Java was proving more popular on servers and memory capacities were increasing significantly, Sun introduced the concept of a *server-class* machine in JDK 5.  This is one that has 2 or more physical processors and 2 or more Gb of memory (if I remember rightly, in JDK 5, the machine also had to *not* be running Windows to count as a server).

On server-class machines by default, the following parameters were set

- Throughput garbage collector (i.e. the parallel collector)
- initial heap size of 1/64 of physical memory up to 1Gbyte
- maximum heap size of 1/4 of physical memory up to 1Gbyte
- Server runtime compiler

Ergonomics provided two command-line flags that allowed a user to set a performance goal for the JVM; the idea being that the JVM would then figure out internally how to achieve this goal by modifying its parameters.  The ultimate goal was to eliminate a lot of the -XX flags that were being used to tune JVM performance manually.

The parameters are:

-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=nnn which sets the maximum pause time you want for GC in milliseconds.

-XX:GCTimeRatio= which sets the ratio of garbage collection time to application time being 1 / (1 + nnn).  This was referred to as the throughput goal.

You can specify either of these goals or both.  If the JVM manages to achieve both of these goals it then attempts to reduce the memory being used (the footprint goal).

There's more detail here:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/ergo5-140223.html

Comment: if a virtual machine run one java web-server, it only can use 1/4 physical  memory, is any way to  increase the -xmx up to 1/2  physical  memory?

Comment: Yes, you can easily change the amount of memory used for the heap using the -Xms (initial size) and -Xmx (max size flags). Using more than half the physical memory in the machine is not, however, recommended.

Comment: a machine has 64GB memory,  i have change -xms=20g -xmx=30g, but the max heap size is always 16g( use jconsole connect to instance, it will show max  heap size parameter), not working.

Comment: I just tried this and firstly you need -Xms20g -Xmx30g (without the equals).
Using jconsole, the report shows committed memory of 20GB but the max heap size is oddly only 28GB.  If I increase mx to 32g the max heap is 30GB. I have no idea why it would show this. I'm unsure why your system is not showing the right values.